# How to Insert Nested data in one go using Ruby on Rails API?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-api

I am trying to insert associated data to DB. I have already created "subcategory" controller and inserted some data which contain id,name only. After that I need to create a "category" controller and need to insert data along with its subcategories. The relation should be in a third table. But I am not sure How can I make it live.

For example :

> **SubCategory**
>
> Id: 1, name: sub1
>
> Id: 2, name: sub2
>
> **Category**
>
> Id: 1, name: Category1
>
> **CategorySubcategory**
>
> Id: 1, category_id: 1, subcategory_id: 1
>
> Id: 1, category_id: 1, subcategory_id: 2

This should be the entries in the join table (CategorySubcategory). It should happen when I create Category. I will pass subcategory ids as json to Category controller.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using

```
class Category
  has_many :sub_categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_categories
end
```

I suggest you check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

And be aware that your json sub_categories should be named sub_categories_attributes in order for this to work.

Comment: I am not able to follow quickly because I am a newbie to ROR. Even though I  have tried and posted above what I did. But I am getting some error says that the member_posts_attribute is unknown.

Comment: should be from the camel cased has_many :MemberPosts. As a rule if thumbs, symbols in ruby are snake cased. the symbol :member_posts will be used to make a relationship to the model MemberPost. Might be a bit confusing, depending on your background. Let me know how you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time ***floum***

I just tried following

**Member Model**

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :MemberPosts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :MemberPosts
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**MemberPosts Model**

```
class MemberPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Member
  belongs_to :Post
end
```

**Members Controller**

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
def create
member = Member.create(member_params)
end
def index
    @members=Member.all
    render json: @members
end
private
  def memberparams
    params.permit(:name,member_posts_attributes: [:member_id,:post_id])
  end
end
```

**Posts Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def create
   @post=Post.new(post_params)
   if @post.save
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end
def index
    @posts=Post.all
    render json: @posts
end
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

**Input Json**

```
{
  "name": "joe", "member_posts_attributes": [
    { "member_id": 1 },
    { "post_id": 2 }

  ]
}
```

Please find where I gone wrong. Please keep in mind that I am newbie to Ruby on Rails. So Please elaborate your findings.

Comment: Any belongs_to, has_many, accepts_nested_attributes should be snake cased : examples : belongs_to :post, has_many :member_posts , etc...

Comment: Your json input is not ok as well, member_id and post_id should be in the same json object.